# Indexing for the columns in ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I have below query, because of the huge data in the MATTER Table, it is taking huge time for LIKE statement to execute, so I was thinking of using the CONTEXT Index and using CONTAIN. 
Shall I do indexing only on Matter_title or some other column as well,. Based on the below select query

Inputs highly appreciated

```
SELECT DISTINCT dm.MATTER_SEQ  
FROM MATTER dm
    ,MATTER_TYPE dmt
    ,MATTER_SUBTYPE dms
    ,STATUS ds
    ,FILING df  
 WHERE dm.MATTER_TYPE_SEQ=dmt.MATTER_TYPE_SEQ
   AND dm.MATTER_SUBTYPE_SEQ=dms.MATTER_SUBTYPE_SEQ
   AND dm.STATUS_CODE NOT IN ('abc','jkl','xyz')
   AND dm.STATUS_CODE = DS.STATUS_CODE
   AND dm.IS_EXTERNAL='1'
   AND dm.IS_DELETED='0'
   AND dm.MATTER_SEQ = df.MATTER_SEQ        
   AND trunc(dm.CREATED_DATE) between '01-NOV-95' AND '02-OCT-18'  
   AND upper(dm.MATTER_TITLE) like(upper (q'{%jdasuidhajsndjahs%}'))
```

Comment: 1) Old join syntax 2) non-sargable expressions `upper(dm.MATTER_TITLE) like(upper (q'{%jdasuidhajsndjahs%}'))` and `trunc(dm.CREATED_DATE) between ...` 3) `DISTINCT` from single table means that you search for existence so your query cold be rewritten

Comment: and what are data types for IS_EXTERNAL & IS_DELETED?   if numeric, then the system is having to do an implicit type conversion which adds a little overhead too.  What are those in statements doing... `AND dm.INDUSTRY_SEQ IN (dm.INDUSTRY_SEQ)  
   AND dm.MATTER_TYPE_SEQ IN (dm.MATTER_TYPE_SEQ)  
   AND dm.MATTER_SUBTYPE_SEQ IN (dm.MATTER_SUBTYPE_SEQ)` in with both sides being the same value..  yes... 1 does = 1 so moving on...

Comment: Thanks xQbert for pointing that issue too

Comment: Another minor point, it looks like `dm.CREATED_DATE` is a `date`, so you probably want date literals instead of varchar literals - `AND trunc(dm.CREATED_DATE) between DATE '1995-11-01' AND DATE '2018-10-02'`

Comment: yup... Sorry in the actual query I am using to_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're already aware that [LIKE with a leading wildcard](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning) ('%ABC') is notoriously inefficient since it typically can't use indexes and does a full table scan.

If the other optimizing suggestions don't help much, you probably would see better performance with a Context index. Be sure to set the SUBSTRING_INDEX preference so it'll specifically prepare the index for infix searches like yours. [See this Ask Tom for more details](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:37336026927381). (If you will also have wildcards in the middle of strings ('ABC%DEF'), you might also want to set the PREFIX options.)

```
begin
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('SUBSTRING_PREF','BASIC_WORDLIST');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('SUBSTRING_PREF','SUBSTRING_INDEX','TRUE');
end;
create index matter_title_idx on MATTER(MATTER_TITLE)
    indextype is ctxsys.context 
    parameters ('wordlist SUBSTRING_PREF');
```

Also note that Context indexes are case-insensitive by default, so you don't need to do UPPER(). I haven't tried using q'' literals with contains, so I'm not sure how this'll work.

```
AND CONTAINS(dm.MATTER_TITLE, q'{%jdasuidhajsndjahs%}') > 0
```

Comment: Thankyou Kfinity.. I will try the same.

Comment: Hey Kfinity, I am getting error that indextype doesnot exist, and I am getting the same error for both Catsys and CtxCAT. Can you help me with that

Comment: Do you have a CTXSYS schema in your database? You might need to install the Oracle Text component. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DFSIG/oracle-text.htm#DFSIG269

Comment: Thanks Kfinity, Your inputs helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating function Indexes  upper(dm.MATTER_TITLE) and second trunc(dm.CREATED_DATE).

Also I am considering that the columns in the Join conditions already have indexes. If not have them indexed.